# Remove the backstage Office 2016 / O365 for business

Tags: microsoft-office

I am not a fan of the backstage.  Until today, I didn't even know it had a name (besides "yet another annoying new Microsoft feature").  I would like to disable it in its entirety.  I've come across a few articles that mention disabling it for the Save and Open dialogs, and that works as intended ([AskVG](http://www.askvg.com/5-tips-to-customize-file-save-page-in-microsoft-office-applications/)).

However, I almost always "Save As" instead of "Save" for a variety of reasons.  There doesn't appear to be a way to remove the backstage for "Save As".

I'd prefer to disable the backstage entirely.  If I can't do that, I would like to  disable it for the "Save As" function.  Is there a way to do either?

**Backstory**

The backstage gets in the way of seeing the document (usually a PowerPoint) when I am using the "Save As" dialog box.  I paste a lot of screenshots into various PowerPoints, and I like to name things descriptively.  However, I can't be descriptive when looking at the backstage.  I would like to look at the actual document when saving the file.  Frequently I find myself saving several different open PowerPoint files and can easily lose track of what their contents are, especially if it's been hours since I made the screenshots.  The backstage adds in several extra steps of trying to save, failing at saving (because I forgot what I was working on), going back to the doc, figuring out a name, then saving again.

I got in a habit of always Saving As because that's how you can version a file.  Also, I'm sure there was a significant element of Microsoft getting in the way, or burning me for just saving and not saving as, though I can't recall at the moment.

Comment: Just to be clear, your asking how to disable backstage, is that correct?

Comment: Yes.  I would like to completely disable it if I could.

Answer (score 5):

Quite late to reply but maybe it helps somebody: If you Save-As by pressing F12 you can bypass useless clicks through the Backstage.

Comment: That's awesome! Who knew it could be that simple of a work around?

Answer (score 0):

There is another option for most of the office apps that you use, and that's to add them to the commands of the *Quick Access* toolbar that appears on the title bar on the left of each Office app.

[image: Example of Quick Access Toolbars]

Note that, in most cases, these commands do bypass the useless Backstage experience (yes - I hate it as much as you do!), but some of the functionality does dump you back at the Backstage.

Dropping down the small arrow ([image: Quick Access toolbar drop-down]) on the right of each QATB will give you a few automatic options, but also allow you to add as many other commands that you want/need to make life easier.

Microsoft Access does not <del>trust you to</del> allow you to use anything but Backstage to create new databases.

I find it ironic that Microsoft allows easy access to the folder structure for people writing documents and spreadsheets, but for those who may know that little bit more, Access has been hobbled!  Come on M$, sort it out, please get rid of this *junk*!